# How to secure JSF application client and server-side REST API module

Tags: java, rest, security, jsf, spring-security

i'm trying to find a solution to implement authentication and authorization into my application which exposes services through a REST API and at the moment has a Web application client:

| Web application client | -> JSF / Primefaces
| REST API | -> JAX-RS / Jersey
 
| Business logic and persistence API | -> EJB / JPA
| Database | -> MySQL

The REST API exposes several services and among them also a login service. I was thinking about preserve the REST statelessness constraint by reading and checking user's credentials against my authentication mechanism (used also behind that login service mentioned above) on every client request.

On Web application side, I might check protected resources access (blocking URI access, enabling/disabling GUI buttons), using the user and associated roles information that I obtain as response after the REST login call, and kept those informations in the HTTP session.

Now, when some user's operation is checked and verified to be granted at Web application level, then a second check will be performed on the REST API level again.

Do you think this approach is correct? 
I was trying to understand whether it is possible to avoid double checking of authorizations on both layers.

Furthermore, I was evaluating the introduction of Spring Security in one or both my layers, may I take advantage from it?

Thanks in advance, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I think two approaches you can take to secure your applicaiton(auth aspect):

1. upgrade `http` to `https`, you can check the certificate whenever client sends a request.
2. authenticate the login process with basic or digest authentication(better digest, if you want to secure enough) and return an unique token back to client. Verify the token when every request arrives.

You don't have to check the user credentials for every request, just check the token.

Comment: HTTPS and digest auth for sure would be big improvements, thanks. However I edited my question trying to better explain my problem: the "token" solution would be good for authentication, but what about authorization?

Comment: I missed that it's a web application, you can use spring security to manage the authentication and authorization at the server side.